# while deploying weblogic 12c java.net.MalformedURLException occurred

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee, deployment, weblogic

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Module named '_auto_generated_ear_' failed to deploy. See Error Log view for more detail.
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deployAutoGenerateEarApplication(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:807)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1438)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:898)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:686)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3087)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Contains: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 12c/patch_wls1211/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/../../../patch_jars/BUG13340309_1211.jar
java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:190)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deployAutoGenerateEarApplication(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:788)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1438)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:898)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:686)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3087)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 12c/patch_wls1211/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/../../../patch_jars/BUG13340309_1211.jar
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:567)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.pathToURLs(LoaderHandler.java:749)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:145)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at java.rmi.MarshalledObject.get(MarshalledObject.java:142)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.unwrap(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1523)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.unwrap(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1559)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:771)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:695)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:520)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:516)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

I have got this exception while deploying application in Weblogic 12c. Can you help me for solving this problem?

"_auto_generated_ear_" it says failed to deploy... So please tell mw how to solve this problem..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to deploy your EAR using [WLST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/config_scripting/using_WLST.html) ? Weblogic using t3 protocol for communication with in itself.

If you haven't tried it, update the question with new stacktrace